# Getting the test deployment directory within an mstest/.NET Core 1.1 unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest

How can I get the test deployment directory within an mstest/.NET Core 1.1 unit test?

#### Details

I'm trying to recreate a mstest and .NET Framework based test in .NET Core 1.1.  Previously there was code that retrieved the test deployment directory by using an exposed test context property, like the code block below.  But with .NET Core, it appears that the TestContext object no longer has a TestDeploymentDir property.

```
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testContextInstance;
        }

        set
        {
            this.testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    ...
    // This worked in .NET Framework, but TestDeploymentDir is not available in .NET Core.
    // What can I use as a replacement?
    string deploymentPath = this.TestContext.TestDeploymentDir
    ...
```

I see that TestDeploymentDir is deprecated, but its replacement DeploymentDirectory is also not available. (Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.deploymentdirectory.aspx )

Comment: Looking here https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/311 it appears that Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns the test working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the Author mentioned, `TestContext.TestDeploymentDir` is deprecated and replaced by `TestContext.DeploymentDirectory`. If it's not available you might have a wrong NuGet Package installed like I did.
It is available if you install the NuGetPackage **MSTest.TestFramework**.